# Multiple Controls needed in JavaFX Tree Table Cell

Tags: javafx

I'm needing different editable controls in a JavaFX TreeTableCell based on an enum attribute value of the row object.
In different cases I need a DatePicker, a TextField, a CheckBox, a ComboBox, or a simple non editable Text field.

I've extended TreeTableCell and overridden the updateItem to handle different cases but that is getting very cumbersome.

Is it possible to create a custom CellFactory Callback to return different subclassed TreeTableCells based on attributes of the row object? How might I go about doing this?

```
public class MyCellFactory implements Callback<TreeTableColumn<MyField,String>,TreeTableCell<MyField,String>> {
    @Override
    public TreeTableCell<MyField, String> call(TreeTableColumn<MyField, String> param) {
        return new MyCell();
    }
}

public class MyCell extends TreeTableCell<MyField, String> {
    private TextField textField;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private Text text;
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    public MyCell() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || getTreeTableRow() == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
        MyField myField = (MyField) getTreeTableRow().getItem();
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (myField.getFieldType().equals(MyFieldType.CheckBox)) {
                if (checkBox != null) {
                    checkBox.setSelected(getBoolean());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(checkBox);
            } else if (myField.getFieldType().equals(MyFieldType.Date)) {
                if (datePicker != null) {
                    datePicker.setValue(getDate());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(datePicker);
            } else {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
        }
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

I've implemented an SSCCE version of James_D's method but am having trouble understanding how to commit and update changes to the different cells. I'll post the corrected version Once I find a solution

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SampleApp extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TreeItem<MyField> fooFields = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("Foo", "Foo", null, false, null));
    TreeItem<MyField> fooText = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("fooText", "fooText", "text", true, null));
    TreeItem<MyField> fooCheck = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("fooCheck", "fooCheck", "check", true, null));
    List<String> fooCombos = Arrays.asList("foo Combo 1", "foo Combo 2");
    TreeItem<MyField> fooCombo = new TreeItem<MyField>(
            new MyField("fooCombo", "foo Combo", "combo", true, fooCombos));
    fooFields.getChildren().addAll(fooText, fooCheck, fooCombo);

    TreeItem<MyField> barFields = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("Bar", "Bar", null, false, null));
    TreeItem<MyField> barText = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("barText", "barText", "text", true, null));
    TreeItem<MyField> barCheck = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("barCheck", "barCheck", "check", true, null));
    List<String> barCombos = Arrays.asList("bar Combo 1", "bar Combo 2");
    TreeItem<MyField> barCombo = new TreeItem<MyField>(
            new MyField("barCombo", "bar Combo", "combo", true, barCombos));
    barFields.getChildren().addAll(barText, barCheck, barCombo);

    TreeItem<MyField> hiddenRoot = new TreeItem<MyField>(new MyField("hidden", "hidden", null, false, null));
    hiddenRoot.getChildren().addAll(fooFields, barFields);

    TreeTableView<MyField> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>(hiddenRoot);
    treeTable.setEditable(true);
    treeTable.setPrefWidth(400);
    treeTable.setShowRoot(false);

    TreeTableColumn<MyField, String> nameCol = new TreeTableColumn<MyField, String>("Name");
    nameCol.setPrefWidth(150);
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<MyField, String>("name"));

    TreeTableColumn<MyField, String> valueCol = new TreeTableColumn<MyField, String>("Value");
    valueCol.setPrefWidth(250);
    valueCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<MyField, String>("value"));
    valueCol.setCellFactory(new MyFieldCellFactory());

    treeTable.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, valueCol);

    HBox root = new HBox(treeTable);
    root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" + "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" + "-fx-border-width: 2;"
            + "-fx-border-insets: 5;" + "-fx-border-radius: 5;" + "-fx-border-color: blue;");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Multi Control Tree Table View");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public class MyField {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    public String fieldType;
    public boolean isEditable;
    public List<String> comboVals;

    public MyField(String name, String value, String fieldType, boolean isEditable, List<String> comboVals) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.fieldType = fieldType;
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
        this.comboVals = comboVals;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getFieldType() {
        return fieldType;
    }

    public void setFieldType(String fieldType) {
        this.fieldType = fieldType;
    }

    public List<String> getComboVals() {
        return comboVals;
    }

    public void setComboVals(List<String> comboVals) {
        this.comboVals = comboVals;
    }

    public boolean isEditable() {
        return isEditable;
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean isEditable) {
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }

}

public class MyFieldCellFactory
        implements Callback<TreeTableColumn<MyField, String>, TreeTableCell<MyField, String>> {

    @Override
    public TreeTableCell<MyField, String> call(TreeTableColumn<MyField, String> param) {
        return new MyFieldCell();
    }

}

public class MyFieldCell extends TreeTableCell<MyField, String> {
    private MyEditingControlProvider controlProvider = new MyCellEditingControlProvider();

    public MyFieldCell() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            MyField myField = getTreeTableRow().getItem();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(controlProvider.getControl(myField));
        }
    }

    protected void commitEdit() {
        super.commitEdit(getItem());
        MyField myField = getTreeTableRow().getItem();
        controlProvider.updateFromControl(myField);
    }
}

public interface MyEditingControlProvider {
    public Control getControl(MyField field);

    public void updateFromControl(MyField field);
}

public class MyCellEditingControlProvider implements MyEditingControlProvider {

    private Map<String, MyEditingControlProvider> providers;

    public MyCellEditingControlProvider() {
        providers = new HashMap<>();
        providers.put("check", new CheckProvider());
        providers.put("combo", new ComboProvider());
        providers.put("text", new TextProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public Control getControl(MyField field) {
        if (field == null || field.getFieldType() == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return providers.get(field.getFieldType()).getControl(field);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFromControl(MyField field) {
        providers.get(field.getFieldType()).updateFromControl(field);
    }

}

public class CheckProvider implements MyEditingControlProvider {
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    public Control getControl(MyField field) {
        if (checkBox == null) {
            createCheckBox(field);
        }
        return checkBox;
    }

    private void createCheckBox(MyField field) {
        checkBox = new CheckBox("Check");
        checkBox.setSelected(getBoolean(field));

    }

    private Boolean getBoolean(MyField field) {
        return field.getValue() == null ? false : convertYNToBoolean(field.getValue());
    }

    private Boolean convertYNToBoolean(String val) {
        if (val != null && val.equals("Y")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String convertBooleanToYN(Boolean val) {
        if (val) {
            return "Y";
        } else {
            return "N";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFromControl(MyField field) {
        field.setValue(convertBooleanToYN(checkBox.isSelected()));

    }

}

public class ComboProvider implements MyEditingControlProvider {
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    @Override
    public Control getControl(MyField field) {
        if (comboBox == null) {
            createComboBox(field);
        }
        return comboBox;
    }

    private void createComboBox(MyField field) {
        comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        resetBox(field);

    }

    private void resetBox(MyField field) {
        comboBox.getItems().clear();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(field.getComboVals());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFromControl(MyField field) {
        field.setValue(comboBox.getValue());
    }

}

public class TextProvider implements MyEditingControlProvider {
    private TextField textField;

    @Override
    public Control getControl(MyField field) {
        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField(field);
        }
        return textField;
    }

    private void createTextField(MyField field) {
        textField = new TextField(field.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFromControl(MyField field) {
        field.setValue(textField.getText());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: *"Is it possible in To create a custom CellFactory Callback to return different subclassed TreeTableCells based on attributes of the row object?"*
No: because the cell that is provided by the cell factory will be reused for different items, e.g. as the user expands/collapses nodes in the table or as the user scrolls. So the cell that is returned must be able to handle all cases. Your general structure is correct: you might want to factor the selection of the control into a separate class in order to simplify the code.

Comment: I’m curious if you found a solution to committing changes/updates from the control provider. My current solution is to pass the reference of MyFieldCell into the getControl() methods instead of just the field. Then call the commitEdit() directly inside the event handler property after an event was triggered (e.g. onAction). This works, but not very elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell that is returned by the cell factory will be reused by the `TreeTableView` as the user expands and collapses items in the tree, or scrolls through the data, etc. So the cell you return must be able to handle all cases, and you cannot return a cell instance that only handles specific rows.

If you want to refactor, you have to refactor the code in the `updateItem(...)` method, which you can do to any degree of modularity you want. A (perhaps extreme) example might be:

```
public interface EditingControlProvider {

    public Control getControl(MyField myField);

}
```

with some specific implementations:

```
public class DatePickerProvider implements EditingControlProvider {

    private DatePicker datePicker ;

    @Override
    public Control getControl(MyField myField) {
        if (datePicker == null) {
            datePicker = new DatePicker();
        }
        datePicker.setValue(myField.getDate());
        return datePicker ;
    }
}
```

and similarly for other controls.

Then you can do

```
public class CellEditingControlProvider implements EditingControlProvider {

    private Map<MyFieldType, EditingControlProvider> providers ;

    public CellEditingControlProvider() {
        providers = new HashMap<>();
        providers.put(MyFieldType.CheckBox, new CheckBoxProvider());
        providers.put(MyFieldType.Date, new DatePickerProvider());
        // etc...
    }

    @Override
    public Control getControl(MyField myField) {
        return providers.get(myField.getFieldType()).getControl(myField);
    }
}
```

And now your actual cell implementation reduces to:

```
public class MyCell extends TreeTableCell<MyField, String> {
    private EditingControlProvider controlProvider = new CellEditingControlProvider();

    public MyCell() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || getTreeTableRow() == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            MyField myField = (MyField) getTreeTableRow().getItem();
            if (isEditing()) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(controlProvider.getControl(myField));
            }
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

If you need to implement the `commitEdit(...)` method in the cell, you can add a method to the interface, e.g.

```
public void updateFromControl(MyField myField) ;
```

with (I think) the obvious implementations throughout, e.g.

```
public class DatePickerProvider implements EditingControlProvider {

    // existing code...

    @Override
    public void updateFromControl(MyField myField) {
        myField.setDate(datePicker.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of refactoring but initial results a very good for this method. Thank you for your thoughtful response! I'll update once I flesh this out.

Comment: In your {CellEditingControlProvider} when the TreeTableView displays another row doesn't it just give you a copy of another row of the same kind?